# Wordpress Plugin Authenticate With Facebook WIth No AppID

Tags: oauth

I am working on my first wordpress plugin and posting to facebook.  I have been looking for the last few days for ways to authenticate with facebook. I have found numerous sites that use the method of having the user create an App and then input the AppID and App Secret.  However, I have used plugins before that use Oauth (I think) as it opens a pop up and the user basically logs into facebook and then says this app (your wordpress site) wants to control things.

Does anyone know of any resources for authenticating with Facebook without the user having to go through the trouble of creating apps?

Examples I have found but they require APPid and App Secrets.

http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/02/post-to-facebook-page-wall-using-php-graph
http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track - OAuth2 is probably what you need. However, all of the end-users won't need to actually create Apps at Facebook; only the admin or person who integrates your plugin into their site will need to do this, which would enable their site (at their specific domain) to access the Facebook API in a secure manner on behalf of whatever user. Facebook wants to know where API requests are coming from, so it can block anyone trying to access their API in an unintended way and throttle spam requests. I don't think there will be a way around this, but I could be wrong...